# How to identify a random number in batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch file that changes a set of numbers (8 Dig) of an ID: user every-time the batch is opened. The issue I'm having is that the initial starting numbers have to be stated as an exact input.

The code will change the ID:12345678 to a random set of numbers then over-right the old file. But what if the "ID:12345678" was already randomized, It would not change anything. Any solutions?

```
:: Edit a text file, change a defined line, add random numbers (8-dig), then save.
:: Created by RU$$

@echo off

Set /a num1=%random% %% 10
Set /a num2=%random% %% 10 
Set /a num3=%random% %% 10 
Set /a num4=%random% %% 10 
Set /a num5=%random% %% 10 
Set /a num6=%random% %% 10 
Set /a num7=%random% %% 10 
Set /a num8=%random% %% 10 

:: not needed (Just displays the random #)
echo %num1%%num2%%num3%%num4%%num5%%num6%%num7%%num8%

:: CD to the dir of text file (remove if in same dir)
cd C:\Users\%username%\Desktop

:: Replace the line of text in .txt file.
powershell -Command "(gc rules.txt) -replace 'ID:12345678', 'ID:%num1%%num2%%num3%%num4%%num5%%num6%%num7%%num8%' | Out-File rules.txt"

pause>NUL
```

Is there a way to use something such as %number% to auto identify the number that is in this place?

```
'ID:%number%'
```

Ex:

```
powershell -Command "(gc rules.txt) -replace 'ID:%number%', 'ID:%num1%%num2%%num3%%num4%%num5%%num6%%num7%%num8%' | Out-File rules.txt"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're already willing to leverage PowerShell from your batch file, why not just do it all at once:

```bat
@Powershell -C "$f=(Join-Path([Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop'))'rules.txt');$i=(Get-Random -Max 99999999).ToString('d8');$x='(?<=ID:)\d{8}',$i;(GC $f) -Replace $x|SC $f"
```

*It should replace any sequence of eight digits which immediatley follow the string `ID:` with a newly created eight digit random number string.*

Comment: Simpler without intermediate vars: `powershell -NoP -C "(gc rules.txt) -replace '(?<=ID:)\d+', ((get-Random -Max 99999999).ToString('D8'))| sc rules.txt"`

Comment: @LotPings, Of course but by the time you've added the data file's full desktop path at `Get-Content` and `Set-Content`, you're example becomes no less unwieldly.

Comment: @Agreed. In case the `Desktop` is relocated, using `[Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')` is th more secure way than simply appending the string `Desptop` to `C:\Users\%username%\` or `%USERPROFILE%\`

Comment: @LotPings That solution simplifies my code 10 fold. Marked as solved, fixed my issue, appreciate yall's help!